# Show/hide Google Maps v2 Cluster Items- android

Tags: android, google-maps

I am using two ClusterManager each with their own items.

I need to toggle (show/hide) those items depending on what ClusterManager they belong to.

**Example**:a button that hides all cluster items that belong to cluster 1.

I am only using Cluster Items and not Markers and thus can't do Marker.setVisibility(Boolean).

I tried to save all cluster items into an array and then iterate thorugh it on the button press but it seems you cannot hide a cluster item.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Based on this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/utility/marker-clustering#introduction), it only show how to add [ClusterItem](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils/blob/master/library/src/com/google/maps/android/clustering/ClusterItem.java).

To use the marker clustering utility, you will need to add markers as ClusterItem objects to the [ClusterManager](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils/blob/master/library/src/com/google/maps/android/clustering/ClusterManager.java). The ClusterManager passes the markers to the Algorithm, which transforms them into a set of clusters. The ClusterRenderer takes care of the rendering, by adding and removing clusters and individual markers. The ClusterRenderer and Algorithm are pluggable and can be customized.

***For hiding the ClusterItem.***

I found a solution in this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22048872/issue-on-removing-item-from-clustermanager), on how to hide the ClusterItem.

Because ClusterManager doesn't implement removing elements.

You can try to use GridBasedAlgorithm(it supports elements remove):

```
clusterMng.setAlgorithm(new GridBasedAlgorithm<MyClusterItem>());
```

Or, for better performance, wrap it with PreCachingAlgorithmDecorator, as ClusterManager does by default:

```
clusterMng.setAlgorithm(new PreCachingAlgorithmDecorator<MyClusterItem>(new GridBasedAlgorithm<MyClusterItem>()));
```